# Jupyter Notebook unable to recognize pandas library: Python

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, libraries

I use **Windows** operating system both personally in my home and at office. 
The **Jupyter Notebook** in my personal laptop is able to recognize **pandas** library. I can read csv file, assign it's content to a **numpy** array and do many things.

I run the same **Jupyter Notebook** file in my office. Latest version of **pandas** is installed and **wheel** is also installed.

Now, the confusing part is 
If I run the code in python console, it looks like this. 
[image]

Absolutely no error at all.

The same thing in my **office's Jupyter Notebook** looks like this. It cannot find **pandas**.

[image]

What could be wrong with my Jupyter Notebook in office's computer? I have restarted the kernel, opened in new browser to no avail.

Thanks in Advance

---

## Edit 1

---

Jupyter Notebook already has pandas and wheel. I can see them when I run `!pip list` command. I even tried to upgrade if there is any latest version of **pandas**.

[image]

The **pandas** and **wheel** in Jupyter Notebook and my local installation has exactly same version installed.

[image]

Both are on same directory: `D:\Projects\Python\DataVisualization`

**And the problem still persists. :(**

---

### #Edit 2

As suggested by some SO users, I created a virtual environment named **VE**. On that virtual environment, I installed **pandas**. Along with **pandas** other libraries were also installed, i.e. **pytz, six, python-dateutil** and **numpy**.

[image]

I opened Jupyter Notebook from the virtual environment. Verified that pandas is installed there. And tried to import pandas. Yet the same error.

[image]

May be something is just wrong with my Chrome browser. It is controlled by system admins and I just can't uninstall and install it at my own volition. Let's see.

---

### # Edit 3

**I tried Jupyter Notebook on Microsoft Edge and it is reporting the same error. So no fault of Chrome.**

Comment: Did you by any chance setup a separate environment/path for your notebook that's different from where your cmd calls python from ? Can you get the path to python from both locations and compare them ??

Comment: @KaranShishoo I did not setup separate virtual environment. I just run jupyter notebook command from a regular folder.

Comment: @KaranShishoo I edited the question to incorporate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not figure out exactly what caused the issue. But the issue vanished after doing a fresh install of Anaconda.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with one notebook using pandas and other notebook failing to import it in VS Code. It happened because I've chosen different versions of Python: the global version had it (so pip indicated it's installed), and another had not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to **install jupyter inside** your virtual env, then start it from within the virtual env.  That way it can see all the packages.

Otherwise Jupyter starts outside with a different python interpreter and cannot see the venv packages.

```
$ pip install --upgrade virtualenv
$ python -m virtualenv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) $ pip install jupyter pandas
(venv) $ jupyter notebook
```

Bob is your Uncle!

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is not included with the Jupiter library. You likely have it installed on your local laptop globally. You need to

```
pip install pandas
```

on whatever environment/ terminal you are launching jupyter from

Comment: I edited question to incorporate your suggestions. It's not working yet.

Comment: hmm weird, can you confirm on seperate cells that numpy and matplotlib are importing ok?

Comment: I tried that too. I opened a brand new file and try importing the libraries there. But no luck. I'll try creating a virtual environment and run Juypter Notebook over there and see how it will react late in the evening today. Thank you for you valuable input Alireza.